# How do I check whether a double's decimal part contains a specific number?

Tags: java, floating-point, double

Is it possible in Java to get the value of a double after the decimal point?

I want my code to produce an error message if the decimal part is 6 (like `double number = 1.6`, or 2.6, or 98.6). If it is not 6, I just want to print "correct".

How do I retrieve the decimal part of the double?

Comment: JavaScript and Java are not the same thing, to get the decimal value you can simply subtract the rounded integer from the double.

Comment: Beware, doubles and exact values are a precarious situation. Consider using a BigDecimal instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String stringNumber=""+number;
if(stringNumber.contains(".6"){
promt user
}
```

Comment: Try this with `1.5999999999999999999D` and you'll get the message... that may be what the OP wanted but the question isn't precise.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking: Impossible - reason: double can *never ever* contain a fractional value of exactly .6 (No number ending in .6 is exactly representable as a double).

But you can check if the *rounded* String representation is .6:

```
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#0.0");
String s = f.format(mydoublevalue);
if (s.contains(".6")) {
    // error
} else {
    // correct
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can floor the double, subtract that value from the double, and then have the fractional part left over for checking.

```
double number = 2.6;
double numberWholePart = Math.floor(number);
double numberFractionPart = number - numberWholePart;

if(numberFractionPart == 0.6) {
    System.out.println("error!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(number - Math.floor(number) == 0.6){
  prompt error
}
```

Comment: Direct comparison with a double is shaky ground. I'd want to add a tolerance on there to ensure you don't get floating point imprecision issues.

Comment: Yes. In practice, 2.6-2 often turns out to be .59999999999998 or something of the sort. The answer here is correct in a sense, but it's unreliable because of the imprecision issue. Don't use a double for this; use BigDecimal.